# Use top 1 and then delete?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table #tmpName with just one column, [Name].

Without using a cursor, I would like to take each row of #tmpName (which is technically one name), do something with that name, and then delete from #tmpName.

I began with something like this, but it's very slow and I eventually get an out of memory exception, which doesn't make sense on a 700-row table. I assume it has to do with the fact that I'm not ordering when doing a delete top 1.

```
drop table #tmpName ;
with cte as (
    select Name from [Employees]
    group by Name
)
select Name into #tmpName From cte
declare @count int = 0
while @@rowcount <> 0
begin
    select top 1 Name From #tmpName order by Name asc
    --do stuff with top 1
    delete top (1) from #tmpName
    select @count = @count + 1
    select @count
END
```

I figured then that I could use this DELETE to better remove TOP 1, but I'm not sure how to process each one I delete.

```
WITH q AS
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 Name into @Name 
    FROM    #tmpName 
    order by Name 
    )
DELETE
FROM q
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: `while @@rowcount <> 0 begin ...  select @count END` once started is an infinite loop. The last select of the loop always returns the value of @count and sets @@rowcount to 1 so the loop will happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- once you have data in the temp table, you could something like this....

```
-- populate temp table
select Name INTO #tmpName
from [Employees]
group by Name

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100);

while EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #tmpName)
 BEGIN
      select top 1 @Name = Name From #tmpName

      -- do stuff with top 1

      delete from #tmpName WHERE Name = @Name
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table #tmpName ;

select row_number() over(order by Name) as rn, Name 
into #tmpName From [Employees];

declare @count int = (select count(*) from #tmpName)
declare @rn int = 1

while @count > 0

begin

select Name From #tmpName where rn = @rn
--do stuff with top 1
delete from #tmpName where rn = @rn
set @count = @count - 1
set @rn = @rn+1
select @count

end
```

A `cte` is not needed.  You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider a cursor.  You can do what you want with the `output` clause:

```
DECLARE @namet (name varchar(255));

WITH todelete as (
      SELECT TOP 1 Name
      FROM #tmpName 
      ORDER BY Name 
    )
DELETE FROM todelete
OUTPUT name into @namet;

SELECT @name = name FROM @namet;
```

You can put this logic into a loop.

However, I would recommend that you just add another column to the table and enumerate that.